# Better EdgeDetect[GeoDisplay[]] graphics

Tags: geographics

I was inspired by [this blog post](http://geoffboeing.com/2017/01/square-mile-street-network-visualization/) visualising street networks and linking that to urban form.  I thought I could whip something similar up in Mathematica using GeoGraphics and EdgeDetect.

Considering my skill level I was pleasantly surprised I could whip something up within a few minutes that got me 90% of the way there using some natural language queries for the city list.

I would need to work on the layout of the table and figure out how to make the images bigger but I'd be happy with this as a bit of homework from a high school student who then went on to compare and contrast.

My question is how to get some better graphics - the EdgeDetect is finding the lables of GeoGraphic and the detected lines are a bit rough.

Any ideas?

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[{city, EdgeDetect[
GeoGraphics[city, GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], ImageSize -> Full]]},
{city, {Auckland, Brisbane, Canberra, Hong Kong}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other edge-detection algorithms. For example:

```
GradientFilter[GeoGraphics["Canberra", GeoRange -> Quantity[1,"Miles"],
           ImageSize -> Full], 3]// ImageAdjust
```

makes it single-edged rather than double-edged. Another option is to binarize before taking the gradient.

```
GradientFilter[Binarize[GeoGraphics["Canberra", GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], 
            ImageSize -> Full]], 1] // ImageAdjust
```